# MySql max is returning minimum value

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

I have table rank and inside I have five different columns I want to fetch row record where I have maximun value for instance I have a column phd_ratio so I said:

```
SELECT * FROM rank HAVING max(phd_ratio)
```

Meaning I wanted to fetch row record where value was maximum but it returned me very first row where phd_ratio value was minimum so is there any way to do this?

Comment: `HAVING phd_ratio = MAX(phd_ratio)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may either use a subquery to find the maximum `phd_ratio`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM `rank`
WHERE phd_ratio = (SELECT MAX(phd_ratio) FROM `rank`);
```

Or use a `LIMIT` query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM `rank`
ORDER BY phd_ratio DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

The second version is not suitable if two or more records could be tied for the highest `phd_ratio`, and you require all ties.  In that case, use the first version.  Also, as of MySQL 8+, `RANK` is a reserved keyword, and you should avoid naming your database tables and objects using it.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using one of the two

SELECT * FROM rank WHERE phd_ratio = ( SELECT MAX(phd_ratio) FROM rank )

OR

SELECT * FROM rank ORDER BY phd_ratio DESC LIMIT 1

Answer (score 0):

You could use `INNER JOIN` to join your data with the max phd_ratio :

```
select t.*
from `rank` t 
inner join (
  select max(phd_ratio) as phd_ratio
  from `rank`
) as s on s.phd_ratio = t.phd_ratio;
```